# Angular-Bootstrap "Possibly unhandled rejection: undefined thrown"

Tags: angularjs, angular-bootstrap

I was writing test code when I ran into this weird issue. If I do a `$rootScope.$digest();` after doing a `myModal.dismiss();` I get a `Possibly unhandled rejection: undefined thrown`. I looked at the unit tests for Modal in the angular-bootstrap library and I notice they are doing some stuff with `$animate`. Maybe that's related?

```
it('tests weird failure', function(){
  var myModal = this.$uibModal.open({
    template: '<div class="modalTwo"></div>',
    size: "md"
  });

  this.$rootScope.$digest();
  myModal.dismiss();
  this.$rootScope.$digest();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not certain whether this helps, but it might.  I had working tests that involved the $uibModal being dismissed, but when I ran npm install for my project on a new machine I started seeing this error for one of them.  My issue ended up being that I wasn't handling the case of a rejected promise in my code under test.  The odd part was that the tests still ran on my old machine so I did a bit of digging (admittedly not a ton) and found that the version of karma-jasmine was different between the two machines (1.0.2 and 1.1.0).  I believe that's why I get the error on one machine and not the other.

Code under test to reproduce the issue:

```
$confirm({
    text: 'Are you sure you want to do this?',
    title: 'Are you sure?'
}).then(
    function() {
        $scope.model.things.pop();
    }
);
```

The spec to test this code for a rejected promise:

```
scope.model.things = [{id: 1}, {id: 2}, {id: 3}];

deferred.reject();

expect(scope.model.things).toEqual([{id: 1}, {id: 2}]);
```

Notice that in the code under test there is no second function that would be called in the event $confirm (something from the angular-confirm library) is rejected (in this case that means the user clicked No on a popup).  Making this small change to my code allowed my test to pass:

```
$confirm({
    text: 'Are you sure you want to do this?',
    title: 'Are you sure?'
}).then(
    function() {
        $scope.model.things.pop();
    }, function() {}
);
```

The only difference here is that I have an empty function to "handle" the rejected promise.  I hope this helps in some way.

Comment: I ran into some other errors and ended up discovering that I had also updated Angular to 1.6.x from 1.5.x.  That resolved the other issue I was having and I think this may have been related to it as well.